# Packaging Jar using SBT assembly

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt-assembly

How do packaging a jar by selected scala classes using SBT assembly. While using SBT full project is created as jar. Is there a way to exclude the classes? Please help .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assemblyMergeStrategy` with `MergeStrategy.discard` to discard to the classes that you want, like:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
  case "application.conf"                            => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "unwanted.txt"                                => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Reference:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy